# Query for postgres database to fetch record from query parameter stored inside an array within an attribute of the table

Tags: postgresql

I have a table in a postgres database whose columns are shown below.

```
CREATE TABLE Student(
  name VARCHAR,  
  course_id SMALLINT[]
);
```

I am trying to write a SQL query that fetches the name of the Student that has course_id 1 in its vector.

So if an entry has

```
INSERT INTO Student ( name, course_id ) VALUES ( 'john', ARRAY [1,2,3] );
```

The query will return 'john' since 'john' has a course_id 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use postgres contains:

```
select * from Student where course_id @> array[1]
```

```
CREATE TABLE Student(
  name VARCHAR,  
  course_id SMALLINT[]
);
```

```
INSERT INTO Student ( name, course_id ) VALUES ( 'john', ARRAY [1,2,3] );
INSERT INTO Student ( name, course_id ) VALUES ( 'john2', ARRAY [2,3] );
INSERT INTO Student ( name, course_id ) VALUES ( 'john3', ARRAY [1] );
```

```
select * from Student where course_id @> array[1]
```

| name | course_id |
| --- | --- |
| john | {1,2,3} |
| john3 | {1} |

> ```
> SELECT 2
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/tDNYs5vx)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ANY()` operator:

```
select * 
from student 
where 1 = any(course_id);
```