# Postgres Query with optional query params stored inside an array within an attribute of the table

Tags: postgresql

This question is an extension to my earlier question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75533424/query-for-postgres-database-to-fetch-record-from-query-parameter-stored-inside-a)

I have a table in a postgres database whose columns are shown below.

```
CREATE TABLE Student(
  name VARCHAR,  
  course_id SMALLINT[]
);
```

I am trying to write a SQL query that fetches the record of Student that has course_id 1 in its vector. It may happen that the course_id is `optional`. The query always contains `name`.

So if an example entry

```
INSERT INTO Student ( name, course_id ) VALUES ( 'john', ARRAY [1,2,3] );
```

The query will return 'john' since 'john' has a course_id 1

What I have tried so far:-

I am sure,I will have to utilize ANY and COALESCE together, but I am not being able to come up with a well defined query.

Comment: 1) You have not showed what you tried or an example of expected output. 2) Does `select name from student where 1 =  any(course_id);` not work? 3) I don't see how you can get have  the string value `optional` in an `integer` array.

Comment: Assuming `optional` actually using  a `NULL` course_id for comparison then: `select coalesce(course_id_val, course_id[1] ) = any(course_id);`.